# Matrix template istream& operator>> error stuck at the input

Tags: c++, templates, istream

Hi I'm having a weird problem where after trying to get the >> operator to work i get stuck at the
`is >> rows;` line. No matter what I try to write it's stuck. I'm using Qt Creator with MinGW and Cmake.

What's funny is a way that I can prevent the problem; when I have my antivirus try to capture my program I don't have this issue. Debugging does not seem to help either. What am I doing wrong?

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

template<typename T = int>
class Matrix {
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> matrix_;

public:
    Matrix() {}

    Matrix(const size_t rows, const size_t cols) {
        std::vector<std::vector<T>> matrix(rows);
        for(size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            matrix[i] = std::vector<T>(cols, static_cast<T>(0));
        matrix_ = matrix;
    }

    Matrix(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& matrix) {
        const auto size = matrix.front().size();

        auto it = std::next(matrix.begin());
        for(; it != matrix.end(); it++)
            if(it->size() != size) throw "Different sizes";

        matrix_ = matrix;
    }
    template<typename F>
    static Matrix fill(const size_t rows, const size_t cols, F f) {
        std::vector<std::vector<decltype(f())>> matrix(rows);

        for(size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            std::vector<decltype(f())> row(cols);

            for(size_t c = 0; c < cols; c++) row[c] = f();

            matrix[r] = row;
        }

        return matrix;
    }
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Matrix& m) {
        double rows, cols;

        std::cout << "Size of rows: ";
        is >> rows;
        std::cout << "Size of colums: ";
        is >> cols;

        std::vector<std::vector<T>> matrix(rows);

        for(size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            std::vector<T> row(cols);

            for(size_t c = 0; c < cols; c++) is >> row[c];

            matrix[r] = row;
        }

        m = matrix;

        return is;
    }
};

int main() {
    Matrix<double> D;
    std::cin >> D;
}
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, one line at a time, what did you see?

Comment: Lookout for potential problems with lines like `const auto size = matrix.front().size();`. If `matrix` is empty, you'll have UB.

Comment: here are the different states of my debug
https://imgur.com/a/kb9tKTR

Comment: It didn't get stuck for me. I entered 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 and it read it and exited.

Comment: Why do you use `double` for `rows` and `cols` though? Surely, they should be some kind of integer?

Comment: well earlier it was size_t but i was thinking that was why it was stuck and changed the type to double

Comment: the only additional clue i have is that when i force stop the program spits out an additional "Size of rows:"

Comment: Are you running it from within the IDE? Perhaps stdin isn't properly connected to the started program. Try running the program directly from the command line. You can also add tests to verify that reading actually works. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/bYMns69zK)

Comment: I'm using the build and run of QTcreator and i write all of my cin from the Application output window () in the imgur links it would be "3.Komunikaty aplikacji"

Comment: Try running your compiled program from the command line instead.

Comment: I'm sorry but could you please explain step by step how do I need to do this?(Never used command line to run a compiled program)

Comment: Have you executed _any_ program from the command line? Are you using Windows, Mac, Linux or something else?

Comment: using windows and i had one/two lessons in school so I can navigate cmd with cd but nothing else

Comment: Ok, navigate to the directory where your project is. After you've compiled, you should find an `.exe` file in one of the subdirectories. Start that by just typing its name.

Comment: ok got it. It works fine

Comment: Great - so, if it doesn't work from within the IDE it could be a problem with stdin or something else. You can run it from the command line until you can ask your teacher about how to make it work from within the IDE too.

Comment: Well seems like i need to ask him for help whanks everyone for help :)